# Как сделать всё по центру?

Tags: xml, android-xml

У меня есть GridLayout, как в нем все линеарлайоуты разместить по центру, и что бы сам ?

Сейчас выглядит всё это так а должно быть всё по центру.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.HomeFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:columnCount="2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
                app:rowCount="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="165dp"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/grad_daily"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Daily Reward"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/daily" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="165dp"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    app:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/grad_daily"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Spin Whell"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/spin" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="165dp"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/grad_daily"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Scratch Card"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/card" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="165dp"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/grad_daily"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Refer and Earn"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/refer" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="165dp"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/grad_daily"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Watch Video"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/video" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="165dp"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/grad_daily"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Play Quiz"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/quiz" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_home"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:text="Viktor"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0952234567"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/wd"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="26dp"
                    android:layout_height="26dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/coin"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circleImageView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:text="20"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```